# Парсинг 2 таблиц с одинаковым классом diva

Tags: java, jsoup

Eсть div *entry* класса updatetablebody.

В него вложено 2 id которые называются version и description.

Ниже на странице есть так же div *entry* с классом updatetablebody

Но в него вложено 2 id которые называются patch и description.

Мне нужно распарсить эту страницу таким образом, чтобы первый div *entry* с его id парсились отдельно от второго diva *entry*.

```
    public static void SomeMethod() throws IOException{

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

    Elements entries = doc.select(".updatetablebody #entry");

    System.out.println("Somthing: ");

    for (Element entry : entries) {
        if (entry.hasAttr("div.patch")) {
            Element patch = entry.selectFirst("#patch");
            assert patch != null;
            String patchText = patch.text();

            Element descriptionPatch = entry.selectFirst("#description");
            assert descriptionPatch != null;
            String descriptionPatchText = descriptionPatch.text();

            System.out.println("Patch: " + patchText);
            System.out.println("Description: " + descriptionPatchText);
        }
        else {
            Element version = entry.selectFirst("#version");
            assert version != null;
            String versionText = version.text();

            Element description = entry.selectFirst("#description");
            assert description != null;
            String descriptionText = description.text();

            System.out.println("Version: " + versionText);
            System.out.println("Description: " + descriptionText);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class = "updatetablebody">
<div id="entry">
<div id="version"><a href="/ru/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_7.32c" title="Версия 7.32c">7.32c</a></div>
<div id="description"><span id="7.32c"></span>
<ul><li><span class="image-link"><a href="/ru/wiki/Phantom_Lancer" title="Phantom Lancer"><img alt="Spirit Lance icon" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dota2_gamepedia/images/f/fd/Spirit_Lance_icon.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/18?cb=20120425195445" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="18" height="18" class="noprint" data-image-name="Spirit Lance icon.png" data-image-key="Spirit_Lance_icon.png" data-relevant="0"></a> <a href="/ru/wiki/Phantom_Lancer#Spirit_Lance" title="Phantom Lancer">Spirit Lance</a></span>
<ul><li>Дальность применения увеличена с 525/600/675/750 до 600/650/700/750.</li>
<li>Замедление <a href="/ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F" title="Скорость передвижения">скорости передвижения</a> увеличено с 10%/18%/26%/34% до 14%/21%/28%/35%.</li></ul></li></ul></div>
</div>

<div class = "updatetablebody">
<div id="entry">
<div id="patch"><a href="/ru/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_4_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F_2021" title="Обновление от 4 ноября 2021">4 ноября 2021</a></div>
<div id="description"><span id="2021-11-04"></span>
<ul><li>Updated <span class="image-link"><a href="/ru/wiki/Phantom_Lancer" title="Phantom Lancer"><img alt="Doppelganger icon" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dota2_gamepedia/images/e/e2/Doppelganger_icon.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/18?cb=20140924015254" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="18" height="18" class="noprint ls-is-cached lazyloaded" data-image-name="Doppelganger icon.png" data-image-key="Doppelganger_icon.png" data-relevant="0" data-src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dota2_gamepedia/images/e/e2/Doppelganger_icon.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/18?cb=20140924015254"></a> <a href="/ru/wiki/Phantom_Lancer#Doppelganger" title="Phantom Lancer">Doppelganger</a></span> ability tooltip.</li></ul></div>
</div>
```

У меня получается что-то вроде такого, но это не работает и парсит только div где id version и description. И, получается, позже возникает проблема с NullPointerException. Так как description еще есть и он его видит, а вот version закончились. Помогите, кто чем сможет)

Comment: Приведите HTML-разметку, т.к. не понятно что за "entry" и "id", которые ещё и называются... Используйте в редакторе `Ctrl + M` чтоб вставить рабочий пример кода.

Comment: @XelaNimed Добавил кусок кода в пост. Надеюсь там все понятно +- теперь

Comment: Можете сразу исправлять id, т.к. он на то и id, что в рамках одного документа должен быть уникальным (можете заменить id на class). Для обработки можете использовать метод [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) или [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), т.е. получите все элементы с указанным классом или во втором случае удовлетворяющие селектору, а далее в цикле обрабатывайте согласно необходимой Вам логике.

Comment: @XelaNimed Так ведь в том и дело, что это в принципе просто рандомный сайт с которого мне нужно вытянуть данные. Это не я так криво называл тэги и присваивал им id. 
За ответы спасибо, за предоставленную помощь - тоже. Вопрос решил своим способом. Если интересно - покажу)

Comment: В будущем указывайте такие детали сразу в вопросе - это поможет избежать недопониманий и отсеет ненужные вопросы. На счёт то, что Вы можете показать... Здесь, в принципе, принято отвечать на свои-же вопросы, если Вы нашли решение, что поможет в дальнейшем тем, кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой/вопросом. В любом случае, моё предложение, от новых уточнений, никоим образом не изменилось - выбирайте элементы по селектору и обрабатывайте так, как Вам необходимо.

Comment: @XelaNimed Понял Вас. Спасибо еще раз за то, что откликнулись на такой вот вопросик. Удачи в любых начинаниях :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил такой вопрос следующим путем.

```
    public static void someMethod() throws IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URLLogs).get();

    Element updatetablebodyElements = doc.selectFirst(".updatetablebody");

    if (updatetablebodyElements != null) {
        Elements entries = updatetablebodyElements.select("#entry");
        for (Element entry : entries) {

            Element version = entry.selectFirst("#version");
            String versionText = version.text();

            Element description = entry.selectFirst("#description");
            String descriptionText = description.text();

            System.out.println("Version: " + versionText);
            System.out.println("Description: " + descriptionText);
        }
    }
}
```

Селектором нашел первый div с таким классом. Распарсил его и получил нужные мне данные.

Если вдруг кто-то окажется в такой же ситуации - можно найти любую другую таблицу на странице если тот, кто писал HTML-разметку указал одинаковый класс какого-либа дива

```
    public static void SomeMethodButSecondTable() throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URLLogs).get();

    Elements updatetablebodyElements = doc.select(".updatetablebody");

    if (updatetablebodyElements.size() >= 2) {
        Element secondUpdatetablebody = updatetablebodyElements.get(1);
        Elements entries = secondUpdatetablebody.select("#entry");

        for (Element entry : entries) {

            Element patch = entry.selectFirst("#patch");
            String patchText = patch.text();

            Element description = entry.selectFirst("#description");
            String descriptionText = description.text();

            System.out.println("Patch: " + patchText);
            System.out.println("Description: " + descriptionText.replaceAll("Н\\s", ""));
        }
    }
}

 if (updatetablebodyElements.size() >= 2) // проверка действительно ли таких "элементов" несколько. 

Element secondUpdatetablebody = updatetablebodyElements.get(1); // если несколько - .get(index) выбирает нужный div на всей странице.
```